# SQL query to add elements in arraylist

Tags: java, sql

I have written a method stub where in I have this SQL queru in PreparedStatement so far:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id,itemId,userId, sum(I.price) as totalAmount FROM dbo.Orders o 
join dbo.Items I on o.itemId = I.id join dbo.Users u on o.UserId = u.Id where o.id = ?");
            ps.setInt(1, id);
```

**Requirement:**
 to retrieve different values of Items for given order Id and add them to an arrayList.

Here is what my method looks like so far:

```
    public ArrayList<Orders> GetOrders(Connection connection) throws Exception
            {
                ArrayList<Orders> feedData = new ArrayList<Orders>();
            ArrayList<Integer> itemsId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//How do I get items in this arraylist since there could be multiple items for a given order ?
            try
        {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id,itemId, userId, sum(I.price) as totalAmount FROM dbo.Orders o join dbo.Items I on o.itemId = I.id join dbo.Users u on o.UserId = u.Id where o.id = ? group by o.id");
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                Orders o = new Orders();
                o.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
             //how do I add elements itemid's in itemsId array list here.?
                while(){

                }
                o.setItem(itemsId);
                o.setUserId(rs.getInt("price"));
                o.setTotalAmount(rs.getInt("totalAmount"));
                feedData.add(o);
            }
            return feedData;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Edit:

Database schema:

```
create table Users
(
Id int not null primary Key identity(1,1) constraint fk_UserId_Id references Orders(UserId),
name nvarchar(50),
phone nvarchar(10)
);

create table Items
(
Id int not null primary Key identity(1,1) constraint fk_item_Id references Orders(ItemId),
name nvarchar(50),
Price int
);

create table Orders
(
id int not null primary Key identity(1,1),
ItemId int,
UserId int,
);
```

Comment: Can we have your data structure (DB schema)?

Comment: @Amadan: Sure, Updated.

Comment: You didn't update the question, you slipped in a completely different question. "To derive total_price for a given order(i.e sum of prices of all Items for a given OrderId)" and "to retrieve different values of Items for given order Id and add them to an arrayList." are not even similar.

Answer (score 0):

// Is this what you are looking for?

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("
SELECT o.id,o.itemId,userId, sum(I.price) as totalAmount 
FROM dbo.Orders o 
INNER JOIN dbo.Items I on o.itemId = I.id 
INNER JOIN dbo.Users u on o.UserId = u.Id 
WHERE o.id = ?
GROUP BY o.id,o.itemId,u.userId");
 ps.setInt(1, id);
```

Comment: No, I need to create an arraylist for sublist of items column only for a given orderId

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to traverse all records that are returned even if you want to load just 1 order object.

This is a quick mock that I've made, so hold off the criticism, yes it could be implemented better.

```
public ArrayList<Orders> GetOrders( Connection connection ) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Orders> feedData = new ArrayList<Orders>();
    int id = 0; // your Order ID
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement( "SELECT id,itemId, userId, sum(I.price) as totalAmount FROM dbo.Orders o join dbo.Items I on o.itemId = I.id join dbo.Users u on o.UserId = u.Id where o.id = ? group by o.id" );
        ps.setInt( 1, id );
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        ArrayList<Integer> itemsId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Orders o = new Orders();
        boolean populateOrder = true;

        while( rs.next() ) {

            itemsId.add( rs.getInt( "itemId" ) );

            if( populateOrder ) {
                o.setId( rs.getInt( "id" ) );
                o.setUserId( rs.getInt( "price" ) );
                o.setTotalAmount( rs.getInt( "totalAmount" ) );
                feedData.add( o );
                populateOrder = false; // make sure this If executes only once
            }
        }
        o.setItem( itemsId );

        return feedData;
    } catch( Exception e ) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

The above example has one big limitation and that is it works only for single orders (one order ID). If you wish to load more than one orders that code need to change.